# Accessing and summing fields in an embedded 1-N Mongoid model

Tags: ruby, mongoid

I want to calculate the sum of certain fields in all documents contained in an embedded 1-N Mongoid relationship:

```ruby
class Trip
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :points

  field :total_distance, type: Integer, default:->{ calc_total_dist }

  def calc_total_dist
    points.each.inject(0){|sum, point| sum + point.distance}
  end
end

class Point
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :trip

  field :distance, type: Integer
end
```

The idea is so I can do this:

```ruby
p1 = Point.new(:distance=>1000*30)
p2 = Point.new(:distance=>1000*20)
t = Trip.new
t.points << [p1, p2]
t.save
t.total_distance # should be equal to 1000*(30+20)
```

When `total_distance` is supposed to be calculated through the `default` action, it doesn't work (in the example above, `total_distance` returns 0).

However, when the same code is called on the model instance, it does work:

```ruby
t.points.each.inject(0){|sum, point| sum + point.distance}
t.points.sum(:distance)
```

In the `calc_total_dist` method, it looks like `points` doesn't access the real objects. So how do you correctly reference embedded documents from *within* the model itself?

Answer (score 1):

Try `Criteria#sum` method

```
points.sum(:distance)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I got the same result. I added more details to the question to clarify.